# Diffrence b/w "Hangup" and "Remote end Busy" in asterisk while calling through call file?

Tags: asterisk, voip

I am trying to make a call through call file it works fine but I was trying to check all the possible message displayed in cli when like user hangs the call,call to switch off number,if user is busy to other call.In case If user cuts the call the status is sometimes hangup and sometime busy .Exact message is given below

```
Call Failed To Go through, reason (5) Remote end is Busy
Call Failed To Go through, reason (1) Hangup
```

I don't know what the reason is as it display different messages everytime? and where to find meaning of error code (5) and (1) so I can look into details.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly enough, the reason codes returned back for call files are not the same as the canonical [Asterisk hangup cause codes](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Hangup+Cause+Mappings). Instead, most likely for historical compatibility reasons, call files use their own mechanism for what happened to a call. In this case, that would be:

- 0 - "Call Failure (not BUSY, and not NO_ANSWER, maybe Circuit busy or down?)"
- 1 - "Hangup"
- 2 - "Local Ring"
- 3 - "Remote end Ringing"
- 4 - "Remote end has Answered"
- 5 - "Remote end is Busy"
- 8 - "Congestion (circuits busy)"
- (any other value) - "Unknown"

The interpretation of these should mostly be:

- 1 or 4 - the call was answered by the remote party
- 2 or 3 - the call was terminated by the initiator before the call was answered
- 5 - the remote end was busy
- 8 - the remote end was congested
- 0 or any other value - something bad happened to the call

Comment: what do you mean by `1 or 4 - the call was answered by both parties` .In outbound call we call only one number

Comment: You're right; that should say the call was answered by the remote party. In this particular context, it merely means that the initiator - Asterisk - didn't cancel the outbound call.